# Grid layout using flex In React Native

Tags: react-native

I am using flex to display some profile.

```
<View style={styles.flexContainer}>
    <View style={styles.profileImgContainer}  >
        <Image style={styles.profileImg}/>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.name}>
      <Markdown>{user.name}</Markdown>
    </View>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  flexContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  ...,
});
```

I want to put Image in center of col1 using row1 and row2. 
I want to put Markdown in col2 of row1.

My flex container should look like this.

```
    col1 | col2 |
row1     |______|
         |      |
row2 ____|______|
```

How I can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Code:**

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={styles.col1}>
      <Image source={{uri: 'https://www.deine-tierwelt.de/magazin/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/10/Australian-Cattle-Dog-1000x570.jpg'}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.col2}>
      <View style={styles.row1}>
          <Text> Username </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.row2}>

      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 1}} />
</View>
```

**Stylesheet:**

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    padding: 8,
  },
  col1: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'gray'
  },
  col2: {
    flex:1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  row1: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray'
  },
  row2: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'darkgray'
  }
```

**Demo:**

https://snack.expo.io/eoENHOHvq

Answer (score 1):

Check below code

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    {/* column 1 */}
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Image
            style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
            source={{
                uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
            }}
        />
    </View>
    {/* column 2 */}
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {/* row 1 */}
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
        </View>
        {/* row 2 */}
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.